# Bash: Changing a specific line in a file, to something which includes the line

Tags: bash, file

I'm trying to change a file like this:

```
Hello
My name is [Bob]
My age is 34
```

Should turn into:

```
Hello
My name is [Bob]SomeText[Bob]SomeText
My age is 34
```

However, to make it easier, I know that the 'string' i'm looking for will ALWAYS start with 
`[Bo`

Any help will be appreciated, if you need more info, just say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't really need to use `bash` only, you can use `sed`:

```
 sed 's/\[Bo.*/&SomeText&SomeText/g' filename
```

output:

```
Hello
My name is [Bob]SomeText[Bob]SomeText
My age is 34
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`. Match everything form `[Bo` up to the first `]` and replace it:

```
sed 's/\(\[Bo[^\]]*\]\)/\1SomeText\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 'm/(\[Bo.*?\])/g;$a=$1;s/(.*\[Bo.*?\])/$1sometext${a}sometext/g;' your_file
```

Above solution works provided your [Bo.*] will always be present at the end of the line.
tested:

```
> cat temp
Hello
My name is [Bob]
My age is 34
> perl -pe 'm/(\[Bo.*?\])/g;$a=$1;s/(.*\[Bo.*?\])/$1sometext${a}sometext/g;' temp
Hello
My name is [Bob]sometext[Bob]sometext
My age is 34
>
```

Comment: you don't need the `$a` variable: since you use capturing parentheses in the `s///` command, you can use `$1` multiple times in the replacement part. Then you can also drop the `m//` command. -- `perl -pe 's/(\[Bo.*?\])/${1}sometext${1}sometext/g'`